# Lines in SVG not the same size despite crispEdges

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG image that is being created and enhanced programatically. After creating it, it is drawn on a Canvas. However, the lines do not seem to have the same width, despite having the same value for `stroke-width` and the attribute `shape-rendering` set to `crispEdges`.

The coordinates are calculated in JavaScript (hence the weird numbers). However, some lines seem to be twice as thick as others (see example below). I don't understand why this happens or how I can fix it.

My best guess is that the calculations are not precise enough and the angle is not actually a perfect 45°, resulting in a thicker line. But when I calculate the slope by hand, it's 45°.

Setting `shape-rendering` to `auto` theoretically works, but the circumstances require the lines to be not smooth.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="80" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1">
  <rect id="background" x="0" y="0" width="3201" height="1677" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="0"/>
  <line x1="0.5" y1="71.5" x2="71.2106781186546" y2="0.7893218813452"/>
  <line x1="71.2106781186546" y1="0.7893218813452" x2="141.9213562373093" y2="71.5"/>
  <line x1="141.9213562373093" y1="71.5" x2="212.632034355964" y2="0.7893218813452"/>
  <line x1="212.632034355964" y1="0.7893218813452" x2="283.3427124746186" y2="71.5"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `crispEdges` attribute is to accentuate the contrast between edges in your picture, not to ensure that strokes are drawn with the same width.

You probably want to use `geometricPrecision` instead. However, if it's important to use crisp edges for some reason, try drawing your lines with the same gradients and with their start/end points aligned to the pixel grid (ideally, offset by 0.5 pixels).

Here's your SVG, with minor modifications to ensure the stroke width appears consistent:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="80" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1">
  <rect id="background" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="80" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="0"/>
  <line x1="0.5" y1="71.5" x2="71.5" y2="0.5"/>
  <line x1="71.5" y1="0.5" x2="142.5" y2="71.5"/>
  <line x1="142.5" y1="71.5" x2="213.5" y2="0.5"/>
  <line x1="213.5" y1="0.5" x2="284.5" y2="71.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The problem turned out to be that it's not possible to always align the lines perfectly with the pixel grid without losing precision. Since the input (the lines) is user-generated, there is nothing I can do if I want to keep my crisp edges, so instead I opted to increase the default stroke-width, which makes the problem "disappear".